# Is the empty set empty in all models of set theory?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

In Timothy Bays' excellent [article on Skolem's paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/index.html#note-34), I have been stumped by the following lines:

> Let's grant that the specific element which serves as “the empty set”
> will not remain constant as we move from one model of set theory to
> another—with the empty set in the first model becoming, perhaps, a
> singleton in the second. Nonetheless, we can still use a formula in
> the language of set theory to capture the notion “*x* is the empty
> set” in an essentially absolute way. In *any* model of our axioms, an
> element *m'* ∈ **M** will satisfy the open formula “∀*y* *y* ∉ *x*” if
> and only if the set {*m* | **M** ⊨ *m* ∈ *m'* } is really empty.
> Hence, there's at least a sense in which we can still capture the
> notion “*x* is the empty set” from within the algebraic framework. And
> this point extends more widely—a similar argument would apply to
> notions like “*x* is a singleton” or “*x* has seventeen members.” Even
> on the algebraic conception of axiomatization, therefore, there are
> some set-theoretic notions which we can still pin down pretty
> precisely.

At first he says that the element for "the empty set" will not remain constant from one model to another, but then he goes on to show that the empty set is really the self-same empty set in all models. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the difference between intensional and extensional definitions. We like to think of sets as classes, i.e. every set is definable (remember that we allow parameters, so $A$ is given by the class $x\in y$, where $A$ is taken as the parameter $y$).

But in reality that can easily fail when the model's $\in$ relationship is not the "real $\in$".

The internal empty set is simply the object $\varnothing^M$ (in $M$) such that $M\models\forall x(x\notin\varnothing^M)$. We can show that it is unique in $M$, using the axiom of extensionality. But we can also talk about the empty class, which is the *subset of $M$* which corresponds to the elements of $\varnothing^M$ *inside $M$*. So the empty class of $M$ is always empty, since $M$ thinks that there are no elements inside $\varnothing^M$.

What we do, normally, is identify a set with its class, so $\{x\in M\mid M\models x\in\varnothing^M\}$ is identified with $\varnothing^M$, even if it's not equal to it.

However, since the empty set defines the empty *class*, and that is externally empty, it means that the empty class *of all models* is really just the empty set.

---

Finally, let me now point out that every model of $\sf ZF$ has an initial segment which is truly well-founded, so by Mostowski's collapse lemma we can collapse that initial segment. It is easy to show that this initial segment must always include $V_\omega$, so it includes all the truly hereditarily finite sets, which of course include $\varnothing$.

So in a way, $\varnothing$ is the same in all models, up to a small re-labeling issue.

Comment: I admit I'm still confused here. Do you mean "the elements of $\varnothing^M$ *inside* $M$" or "the elements of $M$ *inside* $\varnothing^M$"? Can you give an example where, as Bays says, "the empty set in the first model [becomes] a singleton in the second"?

Comment: If $M$ is a model of ZF, consider $f$ the permutation of $M$ switching $\varnothing^M$ and $\{\varnothing^M\}^M$. Use $f$ to define $E'$ on $M$ such $f$ is an isomorphism between $(M,E)$ and $(M,E')$. What is $\varnothing^M$ and what is $\varnothing^{M'}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $E$ and $E'$? Are they subsets of $M$ and $M'$ respectively?

Comment: No, $E$ and $E'$ are the membership relations on $M$.

Comment: Okay ... so $\varnothing^{M^\prime} = \{\varnothing^M\}^M$? Perhaps what I'm not understanding, more basically, is what it means for a set/class to be "internally" empty vs "externally" empty.

Comment: @Doubt: Can you understand how $\varnothing^M$ could be different from $\varnothing$?

Comment: I think so. $\varnothing$ is the set $x$ satisfying $\forall y(y\not\in x)$ where $y$ ranges over the universe of sets. $\varnothing^M$, on the other hand, has the same definition, but where (1) the symbol $\in$ may have an interpretation other than set-membership, and where (2) the variable $y$ ranges over only the domain of $M$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Doubt: Yes, but more importantly $\varnothing^M$ is the member of $M$ which satisfies the formula $\forall y(y\notin x)$. Just like $1_G$ is the unique element of a group $G$ satisfying $\forall y(y\cdot x=y)$.

Comment: Okay, so far so good. Now, when Bays says "the empty set in the first model [might become] a singleton in the second", does he mean that, though $\varnothing^M$ contains no elements in $M$, $\varnothing^M$ might indeed contain one element (or more?) in some other model $N$ (which in turn means that $\varnothing^N$ is not $\varnothing^M$)?

Comment: @Doubt: Yes. Exactly. And what I tried to illustrate is that $M$ and $N$ could have the same underlying set, just $\in$ will be interpreted in different ways between the two.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it! Let me test my understanding. So $\varnothing^M$ contains no elements that are in $M$, and $\varnothing^N$ contains no elements that are in $N$, even though it's possible that, within some larger model $Q$, $\varnothing^M$ and $\varnothing^N$ could be non-empty. But, if $Q$ is the class containing all models, then $\varnothing^Q$ is "really just the empty set" (to use your words), even externally speaking. So, while "emptiness" can be pinned down with respect to a certain model $M$, the Skolem paradox says that "uncountability" cannot be so pinned, even within $M$.

Comment: @Doubt: It's not that $\varnothing^M$ contains no elements that in $M$. It's that $M$ thinks that it does not contain any elements. In other words, the binary relation $E$ for which $(M,E)$ is a model of set theory does not have any $x$ such that $(x,\varnothing^M)\in E$. Which means that the collection $\{x\in M\mid (x,\varnothing^M)\in E\}$ is the empty set (in the real universe), even if $\varnothing^M$ is not *really* the *real* empty set.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here. It's taken a while for me to grasp the import of $\in$ taking on non-standard interpretations. But your last statement really clarified it. In my last comment, therefore, I think I should have said "So $\varnothing^M$ contains no elements that are in $M$ *according to* $\in^M$". And, when I said "'emptiness' can be pinned down with respect to a certain model $M$", it's rather the case (please confirm) that "emptiness" can be pinned down with respect to the class concept, according to which "contains" always means "contains".

Comment: @Doubt: Yes. Just be aware that often times when a class defines a set (e.g. the empty class), we will simply identify it with the internal set it defines.